# Selected Option in dropdownlisfor not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, default, html.dropdownlistfor, selectedvalue

I have this model

```
public string Rol { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Perfil:")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione un perfil para el usuario")]
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles
{
    get
    {
        yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Administrador", Value = "1" };
        yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Consultor", Value = "2" };
    }
}
public int IdProject { get; set; }
public string ProjectDesc { get; set; }
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult _Update(string user, string name, string rol)
{
    var obj = new AdministracionDto
    {
        User = user,
        Name = name,
        Rol = "2"
    };
   // ViewBag.Roles1 = new SelectList(AdministracionDto.Roles, "Id", "Name");
    return PartialView("_Update", obj);
}
```

the partial view is a Pop Up, where the user click on link "Actualizar" of the view. and shows the popup

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { style = "register", style = "height: 34px;" } ))
{
    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</b>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { PlaceHolder = "Ingrese nombre", @required = "required", @class = "input-register", style = "height: 34px;" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rol)</b>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Rol, AdministracionDto.Roles, "--Seleccione Perfil", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rol, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <button type="button"class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" value="Create">Actualizar</button>
}
```

but my problem is: that when goes to the actionresult _Update.  I lose  the selected value in the dropdownlisFor . but I need establish the value in "2.

Comment: Change AdministracionDto.Roles to AdministracionDto.Rol in your partial view.

Comment: Can you rephrase what you need ?

Comment: I want establish the value of dropdownlistfor with the variable "string" "rol " of actionresult. but ever load with default value.